# how to add an extra day to the iso format date in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date-format, isodate

Current date Format :2016-05-10T06:34:17Z,I need to add 10 days to the current date ie..2016-05-20T06:34:17 in javascript or in angularjs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add days to JavaScript Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-javascript-date)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a new date based on your string using `Date` constructor.

Use `Date.prototype.setDate()` to set the day of the Date.

Example:

```js
var myDate = new Date('2016-05-10T06:34:17Z');
myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + parseInt(10));
console.log(myDate);
```

Notes: You can create simple "utility" function if you need to use more times this script, example:

```js
var addDays = function(str, days) {
  var myDate = new Date(str);
  myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + parseInt(days));
  return myDate;
}

var myDate = addDays('2016-05-10T06:34:17Z', 10);
console.log(myDate);
```

Related documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate

Comment: Thanks GibboK. I got it.

Comment: Why the `parseInt()`? `.getDate()` returns an integer, so it should be safe to do `myDate.getDate() + 10`.

Comment: @HarishKesari thanks for your comment, if you think my answer as helped you out please do not forget to accept it or upvote it using the "Arrow" and "Tick" on the left side :) thanks!

Comment: @Arnauld I got your point. I added in case a user pass a string instead of number like addDays('2016-05-10T06:34:17Z', '10');

Answer (score 3):

One Liner Solution:

- **Today:**

  `today = new Date().toISOString()`
- **Yesterday:**

  `yesterday = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 1)).toISOString()`
- **Tomorrow:**

  `tomorrow = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 1)).toISOString()`

> Tip: You can add or subtract days to get the exact date from today.